# send dynamic value as a parameter firestore where query

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore

1. I need to compare data from a list to the `firestore` data, where the value for the query is dynamic. I am using python to perform the query:

   ```
   mail='sampoornitb@gmail.com'
   doc_ref = store.collection(u'students').where(u'email', u'==', 'mail')
   ```

   This code is not working with `NameError`.
2. If I use:

   ```
   doc_ref = store.collection(u'students').where(u'email', u'==', 'sampoornitb@gmail.com')
   ```

   It is working fine.

Can you suggest a query that uses a dynamic value as a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put quotes around the name of a variable that you want to pass to the Firestore API.  Quoted strings are taken literally in Python. (It has nothing to do with the Firestore SDK.)

```
mail='sampoornitb@gmail.com'
doc_ref = store.collection(u'students').where(u'email', u'==', mail)
```